# sql syntax error while cflooping in cfquery INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, mysql, coldfusion

CF8 and MySQL5, for loop within INSERT INTO.

I am getting form data and trying to optimize an insert statement to loop within the cfquery. 
The best case scenario would be that the loop is just around the VALUES in order to have a single INSERT, but I had issues in trying to ID the second iteration and put a comma at the beginning of the first INSERT VALUES.
So I went with looping over the entire INSERT. At least that's within the same cfquery. My problem is that I can't get the syntax correct for the 2nd (and beyond) iterations of the loop. It works fine for the first one, and works fine if I take the loop out.

The error I get is:

```
sql syntax error near 'INSERT INTO table(wID,session,xNameVar,xID,set1rt,set2rt,set3rt,set4rt,set5rt,set'
```

Here is the code I use code:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "x1s1xID")><!--- verifies if there is data in field 1 for a specific form section--->
  <cfquery name="qCreateXdata" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#form.sessions#" index="i"><!--- form.sessions is a variable for the number of times to loop --->
      <cfif structKeyExists(form, "x1s#i#xID")><!--- a little redundant but used for other iterations of loop otherwise get a variable not defined error --->
      INSERT INTO table
        (wID,
        session,
        xNameVar,
        xID,
        set1rt,
        set2rt,
        set3rt,
        set4rt,
        set5rt,
        set6rt)
      VALUES
        (#variables.wID#,
        #wCreateFormData["session" & i]#,
        '#wCreateFormData["x1s" & i & "xNameVar"]#',
        #wCreateFormData["x1s" & i & "xid"]#,
        <!--- the below values are not required in form so need to be null integers instead of empty strings if not set in form --->
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x1set1reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x1set1r" & i]))#" />,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x1set2reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x1set2r" & i]))#" />,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x1set3reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x1set3r" & i]))#" />,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x1set4reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x1set4r" & i]))#" />,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x1set5reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x1set5r" & i]))#" />,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x1set6reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x1set6r" & i]))#" />
        )
        <cfif structKeyExists(form, "x2s#i#xID")>
            ,(#variables.wID#,
            #wCreateFormData["session" & i]#,
            '#wCreateFormData["x2s" & i & "xNameVar"]#',
            #wCreateFormData["x2s" & i & "xid"]#,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x2set1reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x2set1r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x2set2reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x2set2r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x2set3reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x2set3r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x2set4reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x2set4r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x2set5reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x2set5r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x2set6reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x2set6r" & i]))#" />
            )
        </cfif>
        <cfif structKeyExists(form, "x3s#i#xID")>
            ,(#variables.wID#,
            #wCreateFormData["session" & i]#,
            '#wCreateFormData["x3s" & i & "xNameVar"]#',
            #wCreateFormData["x3s" & i & "xid"]#,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x3set1reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x3set1r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x3set2reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x3set2r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x3set3reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x3set3r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x3set4reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x3set4r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x3set5reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x3set5r" & i]))#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#trim(wCreateFormData["x3set6reps" & i])#" maxlength="3" null="#NOT len(trim(wCreateFormData["x3set6r" & i]))#" />
            )
        </cfif>

        <!---... you get the idea.....there are 12 total cfif blocks like this --->
        <!--- then I end with a ';' in order to close this INSERT statement and go back to the start of the loop for #form.sessions# number of times --->

        ;
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
  </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `<cfquery><cfloop>` instead of `<cfloop><cfquery>`? I mean - you *are* in fact trying to issue multiple insert statements, aren't you?

Comment: performance - trying to avoid the overhead of cfquery with every loop iteration. For the same reason, optimally I would like to just loop through the VALUES but keeping each separate INSERT is second best.

Comment: You are doing the inserts by `<cfqueryparam>` anyway. Have you *measured* how much of an impact this actually is, or is it more speculation?

Comment: First off, thank you very much for your time and feedback!
From using WebLogic and WebSphere (and JRun long ago), cfquery basically builds the query and gets a connection to the DB. If I loop through 20 cfqueries, I can grab 20 connections which may max out the connections in the pool from a single user interaction. I if loop within the cfquery then I use the same DB connection in the pool to send all this data for the same request. If someone knows that the version of JRun (or whatever) now does not do that then please correct me.

Comment: I don't think it creates a new connection every time. I would say CF keeps it one connection open throughout the request. If the query is completely parameterized, then with each loop iteration (beyond the first) only the parameter values would be sent. (You'd have to have an eye on the DB server traffic to find out if this is actually true for your set-up, though.)

Comment: If all else fails you can remove the `<cfquery>` tag from the loop, and wrap the whole SQL generation process in a `<cfsavecontent>`. When the loop is through, you can send the aggregated SQL with `<cfquery>`. I would recommend against that, because this way you lose the ability to use `<cfqueryparam>`, making your code prone to SQL injection. And it would bloat the query string, making efficient query plan caching on the server side impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could replace your *entire* code:

```
<cfset i_max = 6>

<cfloop from="1" to="#form.sessions#" index="s">
  <!--- do all the 12 blocks you speak of --->
  <cfloop from="1" to="12" index="x">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(form, "x#x#s#s#xID")>

      <cfquery name="qCreateXdata" datasource="#application.datasource#">
        INSERT INTO table (
            wID,
            session,
            xNameVar,
            xID,
          <cfloop from="1" to="#i_max#" index="i">
            set#i#rt
            <cfif i lt i_max>,</cfif>
          </cfloop>
          ) VALUES (
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#variables.wID#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#wCreateFormData["session" & s]#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#wCreateFormData["x#x#s#s#xNameVar"]#" />,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#wCreateFormData["x#x#s#s#xID"]#" />,
          <cfloop from="1" to="#i_max#" index="i">
            <cfqueryparam 
              cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_INTEGER" 
              value     = "#Trim(wCreateFormData["x#x#set#i#reps" & s])#" 
              maxlength = "3" 
              null      = "#Len(Trim(wCreateFormData["x#x#set#i#r" & s])) = 0#" 
            />
            <cfif i lt i_max>,</cfif>
          </cfloop>
          )
        ;
      </cfquery>

    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Hint: Do less copy-and-paste programming, try to find more abstractions for repetitive patterns. ;-) Doing *essentially the same thing* twelve times in a row by copy and paste should set off a big red alarm.

Comment: I agree. I got lazy with this since I was trying to balance an optimal schema with normalization and the number of nulls.

Comment: You got me 99% of the way there. Much thanks and gratitude and I appreciate the lesson!